# Convert Curl To Php not sending data

Tags: php, curl

i use this Curl code in mac terminal

```
curl 'http://www.test.com/courses/ping' -H 'authority: www.test.com' -H 'pragma: no-cache' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'origin: https://www.www.test.com'  -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest'  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors'  -H 'accept-encoding: gzip,deflate, br' --data 'course=3231';
```

The above code works properly
But when Convert to Php  it doesn't work anymore

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.test.com/courses/ping');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "course=3231;");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authority: www.test.com';
$headers[] = 'Pragma: no-cache';
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
$headers[] = 'Accept: */*';
$headers[] = 'Origin: https://www.www.test.com';
$headers[] = 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate, br';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
 }
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: This question is needs more information: "it doesn't work anymore" is not clear. What is the specific unexpected error you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this sounds like a pretty weird method to perform a request and get back the data. Note: This trick only works for GET json api's.

You should just be able to use this:

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents("https://example.com/file?data=something"); // run a request and get back the data

$json = json_decode($data, true); // convert the raw json data to an array to use it in php 

?>
```

For POST requests, check this article about CURL, perhaps you can find your error here: https://www.codexworld.com/post-receive-json-data-using-php-curl/

Alternativly: You can use exec and execute the curl command directly on the server. Example:

```
<?php

$data = exec("curl 'http://www.test.com/courses/ping' -H 'authority: www.test.com' -H 'pragma: no-cache' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'origin: https://www.www.test.com'  -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest'  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors'  -H 'accept-encoding: gzip,deflate, br' --data 'course=3231'");

?>
```

I hope this helped you, I use php for over 5 years and am head php developer at BitBiz and never needed to use CURL for anything inside php, just always got away with tricks like these.